# Megento 1.9.2.3 product images are not displaying, any solution?

Tags: cpanel, magento-1.9

I have install on godaddy `cpanel` hosting `Magento 1.9.2.3` I am trying to add a product image, but its not showing over there. Can anyone give me solution on it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyOUB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error ? I think images are not getting upload correctly in your account and due to that you are facing this issues.